# Changing the language of Ask Ubuntu word processor

Tags: support, languages

My PC's language is German and in this site the word processor is set to German. I can't change it to English so that my mistakes are automatically corrected.

Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: Shouldn't that be like a browser thing ? I don't think it's site-related

Comment: This should probably be on the main site rather than on the Meta. I think. This question kind of enters a grey area, but I still think that it belongs on the main site instead. Have a good day! ;-)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I disagree - we are not talking about using Ubuntu but about using AskUbuntu - should be on topic on AU meta.

Comment: @guntbert: Oh, ok, I supose so, but if this is not actually specfic to this site, nor Ubuntu, then surely it doesn't really belong here at all? And perhaps should be a generic question on one of the other sites. Unless they are using Ubuntu, in which case it should be on the main site and on-topic there so that it can be relevant for other websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firefox you can add dictionaries from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/language-tools/) and change the spell-checking language by right-clicking in a text field and selecting another language.